# JavaScript Map Reduce: weird behavior

Tags: javascript, mapreduce

```
var t = [-12, 57, 22, 12, -120, -3];

t.map(Math.abs).reduce(function(current, previousResult) {
    return Math.min(current, previousResult);
}); // returns 3

t.map(Math.abs).reduce(Math.min); // returns NaN
```

I don't understand why the second form doesn't work. Any explanations are welcomed.

**EDIT**: Technical context: Chrome and Firefox JavaScript engine. See ES5 reduce http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.21

Comment: This is "in browser", I updated my answer.

Comment: @ AsTeR: Specifically, the [ES5 `reduce`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.21), which isn't broadly implemented yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) accepts multiple arguments. This is exactly the same reason this doesn't work for `parseInt` or other functions like that. you need to bind the parameters yourself.

reduce feeds the values like `index` and `array` to `Math.min`

We can confirm this if we follow the following steps:

First, we proxy Math.min:

```
var oldMath = Math.min;
Math.min = function (){
   console.log(arguments)
   return oldMath.apply(Math, arguments);
}
```

Then we run the second version:

```
[-12, 57, 22, 12, -120, -3].reduce(Math.min);
```

Which logs:

```
[-12, 57, 1, Array[6]]
```

Since Array[6] is not a number, the result is NaN

---

Here is a very similar example from MDN:

```
["1", "2", "3"].map(parseInt);
```

While one could expect [1, 2, 3]
 The actual result is [1, NaN, NaN]

`parseInt` is often used with one argument, but takes two. The second being the radix
 To the callback function, Array.prototype.map passes 3 arguments: the element, the index, the array
 The third argument is ignored by parseInt, but not the second one, hence the possible confusion.

Answer (score 3):

[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)'s callback is called passing four arguments:  `previousValue`, `currentValue`, `index` and `array`. And because [Math.min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) is a [variadic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) function, your code:

```
t.map(Math.abs).reduce(Math.min); // returns NaN
```

is equivalent to:

```
t.map(Math.abs).reduce(function(current, previousResult, index, array) {
  return Math.min(current, previousResult, index, array);
});
```

That's why the result is `NaN`: the last parameter, `array`, is not a number.

You can also solve this kind of issue with a [high-ordered function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) like this one:

```
function binary (fn) {
  return function (a, b) {
     return fn.call(this, a, b);
  }
}
```

And then:

```
t.map(Math.abs).reduce(binary(Math.min));
```

will works.